# Akka Generic Custom Directives

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I am using custom directives to validate my params:

```
  def optionalIntParamAs[C](parameterName: String, validator: Int => C Or ErrorMessage): Directive1[Option[C]] =
    parameter(parameterName.as[Int].?)
      .recoverPF[Tuple1[Option[Int]]] {
        case Seq(MalformedQueryParamRejection(name, msg, cause)) =>
          reject(MalformedQueryParamRejection(name,
              s"Invalid value '${msg.split("'")(1)}' for query parameter '$name'.", cause))
      }
      .flatMap {
        case Some(intParam) =>
          validator(intParam) match {
            case Good(c) => provide(Some(c))
            case _       => reject(ValidationRejection(s"Invalid value '$intParam' for query parameter '$parameterName'."))
          }
        case _ => provide(None)
      }
```

to be used in my route as :

```
optionalIntParamAs[PageSize]("pageSize", PageSize.validate) { pageSize =>
  ...
}
```

I would like to have a generic directive so I can write:

```
optionalParam[Int].as[PageSize]
optionalParam[String].as[...]
```

Any suggestion ?

Update: with Stefano's solution we will get this compile error:

> found   : akka.http.scaladsl.common.NameOptionReceptacle[In] [error] 
>   required:
>   akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.ParameterDirectives.ParamMagnet
>   [error]     parameter(parameterName.as[In].?)

why ?